# How to slowly rotate spherical shapes using Lerp?

Tags: c#-4.0, vector, unity-game-engine

I need to slowly rotate spherical shapes which are placed on waypoints. It needs to rotate slowly. How can I achieve this with Lerp?

The code I currently have:

```
if(!isWayPoint5)
{
    //here i"m using turn by using rotate but i needed rotate 
    //slowly is same as turns train in track.
    transform.Rotate(0,0,25);
    isWayPoint5 = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out how to use Quaternion.Lerp on [the wiki-site.](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html)

Using that example:

```
public Transform from = this.transform;
public Transform to = this.transform.Rotate(0,0,25);
public float speed = 0.1F; //You can change how fast it goes here
void Update() {
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(from.rotation, to.rotation, Time.time * speed);
}
```

Comment: @DanPuzey `deltaTime` is the time it took to complete the last frame, and `time` is the time since the game started. `time` gets higher every second your game is running, while `deltaTime`'s time varies based on your fps.